# jQuery add hyperlink with number to identify link

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my textarea when I select text I can click on my hyperlink modal and it opens.

And I can set the title and the url.

> It out puts like `["example"]("http://www.example.com")`

**[Codepen DEMO](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/KNjEEW)**

**Question** How can I get it so when each time I add link it can have its on name and number and link below like explained below.

I am try to achieve it where Reference-style links allow you to refer to your links by names, which you define elsewhere in your document:

```
I get 10 times more traffic from [Google][1] than from
[Yahoo][2] or [MSN][3].

[1]: http://google.com/        "Google"
[2]: http://search.yahoo.com/  "Yahoo Search"
[3]: http://search.msn.com/    "MSN Search
```

MY Script

```
$('#link').on('click', function (event) {
    var textArea = $('#message'),
        len = textArea.val().length,
        start = textArea[0].selectionStart,
        end = textArea[0].selectionEnd,
        selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);

    $('input#title').val(selectedText);

    $('input#url').val('http://');

    $('#save-link').on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#myLink').modal('hide');

        replacement =  '["'+ $('input#title').val() +'"]("'+ $('input#url').val() +'")';


        wrapLink(replacement);
    });
});    

function wrapLink(link) {
    var textArea = $('#message'),
        len = textArea.val().length,
        start = textArea[0].selectionStart,
        end = textArea[0].selectionEnd,
        selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + link + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
    $('#message').keyup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution I have worked it out so far new **[EXAMPLE HERE](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/PbMzvo)**

Old code had couple bugs in it.

```
$('#myLink').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var text = getSelectedText();
    $('#title').val(text);
    $('#url').val('http://');
});    

function getSelectedText() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    return sel;
}

var counter = 0;

$('#save-link').on('click', function(e) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("message");
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
    var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);

    var replace = '[' + $('input#title').val() + ']' + '[' + counter + ']';

    var id = '[' + counter + ']: ' + $('input#url').val();

    counter++;

    if ($.trim(sel) == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace +
        textarea.value.substring(end,len) + '\n' + id;

    }
});
```